# Play music from raspberry pi to pc

Tags: windows

I'm new to raspberry pi and I like the concept and remote apps. I got high quality speakers and a terratec dmx 6fire dac that only works with pc. Since there is no driver for this dac on the raspberry pi and there is no high quality dac around for the raspberry I can only use it with the pc which works great but there is not that many possibilities. Now: Is there a way to play all the music that is played on the raspberry to the pc? and from there it obviously would go to the dac

Thanks for your answers

Comment: Something like http://www.crazy-audio.com/projects/raspberry-pi-for-audio-distribution/ maybe.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to play music files stored on the Pi using your PC, just [use samba](http://raspberrypihq.com/how-to-share-a-folder-with-a-windows-computer-from-a-raspberry-pi/) to share the relevant folders. Then you open a File Explorer window at the Pi's IP address and play the files using any media player you like.

Alternatively, mount the folder you keep your music in as a network drive in Windows. Then whenever the PC boots you have access to the folder and can use it like you would a local data source.

There's no sense in having a nice DAC and using it to play compressed streams of compressed files.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about this topic... But I imagine that if you can get your hands on the source code for the drivers you may be able to compile it on the Raspberry Pi...

Another option may be a plex media server, in which you would stream music from the pi to your PC.

here is a tutorial on how to install the plex server to your PI:
http://www.htpcguides.com/install-plex-media-server-on-raspberry-pi-2/

I hope my limited knowledge of this topic helped a little bit.  haha